# QT "Tick" widget loop

Tags: c++, qt, loops, qt5

I'm trying to understand the correct way to update a widget at frame-time.
The specific problem I'm trying to solve is to set the remaining time of a timer on a label.

I created and started the timer

```
MainTimer = new QTimer(this);
MainTimer->setSingleShot(true);
MainTimer->start(5000);
```

and on the QML I have a label, UI_MainTimerLabel, that I can access through `ui->UI_MainTimerLabel->setNum(int)`.

Since the QTimer doesn't provide a `OnTimerUpdate` signal or callback method, I suppose I have to create some kind of loop to read the timer's value and set it to the label.

Should I do it through a QThread?

```
QThread::create([&]() {
    while(true)
    {
        ui->UI_RemainingTimer->setNum(MainTimer->remainingTime());
    }
})->start();
```

(note: I know that this won't work, but it's not a problem since I'm just trying to understand the concept)

Should I use a 0-timed QTimer?

```
UpdateTimer = new QTimer(this);
//{binding the UpdateTimer end signal to a ui->UI_RemainingTimer->SetNum(MainTimer->RemainingTimer() function}
UpdateTimer->start(0);
```

Should I use a QEventLoop (but I have yet to fully understand what is their correct usage)?

Should I use a user-created "MyTimerLabel" widget that self-updates (in which virtual overridden method?)?

Or is there some other correct way to manage a frame-time update, that I couldn't understand? (I'm trying to get the general correct approach, not the solving approach of this specific problem, though)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you just use the [`QTimer::timeout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#timeout) signal?

Comment: @G.M. you mean the MainTimer::timeout? Doesn't it get called only after the 5000 ms? I need it to update frame-time. Or you mean the 0-timed-timer-method?

Comment: By `QTimer::timeout` I was referring to the signal associated with the `QTimer` class.  What do you mean by `frame-time`?  Sorry, but I'm a bit confused as to exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: My specific problem is how to show the remaining time of MainTimer on a QLabel, but the general question is how do I update a widget in main-loop-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary to update the GUI at every moment? No, each frame is updated every 30ms so something appropriate is to update half of that time, that is 15 ms. So the second timer is set to that period by calculating the remaining time showing it in the GUI:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTimer main_timer;
    main_timer.setSingleShot(true);
    QTimer update_timer;
    QLabel label;
    label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    label.resize(640, 480);
    QObject::connect(&update_timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&main_timer, &update_timer, &label](){
        int rem = main_timer.remainingTime();
        if(rem <0){
            label.setNum(0);
            update_timer.stop();
        }
        else{
            label.setNum(rem);
        }
    });
    label.show();
    main_timer.start(5000);
    update_timer.start(15);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: So the correct (qt?)-way to update a widget "almost-at-frame-time" is through a timed timer?

Comment: @Mewster You have to update it whenever necessary, for example let's say you update the number every millisecond but your screen is repainted at 30Hz ie 33.33ms so you will have modified it 30 times but Qt will only paint the last one only update internal states of the class but they are not necessarily painted.

Comment: Is there any agnostic way to know from QT the correct rendering-time of the application, or it's not a manageable case?

Comment: @Mewster So in this specific case you want to show the remaining time of the timer so knowing that the update rate of the screen is 33ms it will only be necessary to update it to a shorter time since visually our eyes are not so fast. So I use the second QTimer at 15 ms, and then use the Qt form to notify me: through a signal, this signal is connected to a function, in this case a lambda method, and in that function I updated the GUI, So yes, it is the Qt way to update the GUI.

Comment: @Mewster No, you do not really know exactly how long Qt is updated, since you can see that there are delays, for example a delay in the screen painting, a delay in Qt when listening to OS events, a delay in transmitting those data to the components of Qt, another delay by the calculations of our application. And in general in an application it is not necessary the precision, if it is painted in 33.33ms or in 33.34 ms it is irrelevant.